# Convert bytes to a "human" string

Tags: python-3.x, converters

I'm attempting to convert a bytes string to a more "human view" one, but I don't know to which format convert to. Anyway I've already tried without success.

These are some examples:

```
b'\xe8t\xe6,\xf1:0\x10\xb3\x18\x8b\xfd\x08\x00E\x00\x004M[@\x00@\x06\x92\xae\xc0\xa8\x01h\x97e\x01E\xc4\xd6\x00PW-\xf8\x06h\x17\x9a\x86\x80\x10\x01\x06\\\xe5\x00\x00\x01\x01\x08\n\x00/\xf6\xe8\x81\xae.X'
```

or

```
b'\xe8t\xe6,\xf1:0\x10\xb3\x18\x8b\xfd\x08\x00E\x00\x004p\xd5@\x00@\x06o4\xc0\xa8\x01h\x97e\x01E\xc4\xee\x00P\xacw\xb7\xca\xa2\xe9\x96\xf8\x80\x10\x00\xed}E\x00\x00\x01\x01\x08\n\x00/\xf7 \x17$+\xf9'
```

or

```
b'\xe8t\xe6,\xf1:0\x10\xb3\x18\x8b\xfd\x08\x00E\x00\x004p\xdd@\x00@\x06o,\xc0\xa8\x01h\x97e\x01E\xc4\xee\x00P\xacw\xbc\x06\xa2\xe9\x98\xda\x80\x10\x00\xf5\x0f\x82\x00\x00\x01\x01\x08\n\x000*\xf0\x17$_\xc6'
```

or

```
b'\x01\x00^\x00\x00\x01\xe8t\xe6,\xf1:\x08\x00F\xa0\x00$O\x9d\x00\x00\x01\x021\xef\xc0\xa8\x01\xfe\xe0\x00\x00\x01\x94\x04\x00\x00\x11d\xec\x9b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00'
```

I've taken these from sniffing with scapy library, but now I really can't convert them.

Could you please show me the way?

Comment: The way to do what? You want us to decide what format you should convert them to? That makes no sense; convert them to a format that you want to see them in.

Comment: That's the most human readable binaries can be. Converting them back to binary is not human readable at all. The only printable text are those in the range between `\x20` and `\x7d`.

Comment: look at this: https://github.com/phaethon/scapy/blob/master/doc/scapy/usage.rst#hex-string as you can see, it converts from bytes to more human view, using Ether. But when I do that, it raises a wrong layer error. So is there a way to convert all sniffed packet? Sorry, I'm a noob and I can't do that. I tried different ways... but nothing

Comment: why if I convert these bytes string in the idle3 using "Ether" it works and it converts in a more human view one, and if I convert from a script executed in the terminal it doesn't work?